# How to multithread a download in client-side javascript

Tags: javascript, multithreading, download, file-writing

I have very large (50-500GB) files for download, and the single-threaded download offered by the browser engine (edge, chrome, or firefox) is a painfully slow user experience. I had hoped to speed this up by using multithreading to download chunks of the file, but I keep running into browser sandbox issues.

So far the best approach I've found would be to download and stuff all the chunks into localStorage and then download that as a blob, but I'm concerned about the soft limits on storing that much data locally (as well as the performance of that approach when it comes to stitching all the data together).

Ideally, someone has already solved this (and my search skills weren't up to the task of finding it). The only thing I have found have been server-side solutions (which have straightforward file system access). Alternately, I'd like another approach less likely to trip browser security or limit dialogs and more likely to provide the performance my users are seeking.

Many thanks!

Comment: Generally the download response will use up all the actual bandwidth that's available as it is. Your bottleneck is the network, not the browser.

Comment: @Pointy --Thank you!  The download is happening around 120mbs, nowhere near the 10gbs that is available (and yes, the full link bandwidth was available for the testing). I suppose it might be some _other_ network issue, however. I'm not sure how to differentiate them. Perhaps the user will have some ideas.

Comment: I think you may be confused by BITS and BYTES. Speed tests show in BITS whilst when downloading it's measured in BYTES. There's 8 bits in a byte so 1000bits (read 10Gb) would give you 125bytes (read 125MB) which seems quite accurate in what you are seeing. [Here's a good explanation](https://superuser.com/questions/617386/why-is-my-actual-download-speed-less-than-that-found-by-by-speedtest-net?answertab=votes#tab-top). Also it's a very bad idea to store such a amount huge of data on the client (as in LocalStorage)

Comment: @MathiasW -- Thank you! Yes, I am aware of the difference. I'm seeing about 80% of the network bandwidth (admittedly over a very fat pipe) consumed; nowhere near the 80-90% I was hoping for.          I agree it's a terrible idea to store that much data localStorage; I just don't see a better option. I was hoping someone could suggest a superior alternate approach.

Comment: Do you control both the client end and the server end?  Is there per-connection throttling somewhere in the server DMZ?

Comment: Part of the issue turns out to have been the download of multiple files over a single thread; the file metadata setup was a major slowdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One cannot. Browsers intentionally limit the number of connections to a website. To get around this limitation with today’s browsers requires a plugin or other means to escape the browser sandbox.

Worse, because of a lack of direct file system access, the data from multiple downloads has to be cached and then reassembled into the final file, instead of having multiple writers to the same file (and letting the OS cache handle optimization).

TLDR: Although it is possible to have multiple download threads, the maximum is low (4), and the data has to be handled repeatedly. *Use a plugin or an actual download program such as FTP or Curl.*